# Can't create NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, initialization, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

Strange things happens to me, I try to create mutable dictionary, but it return an immutable.

```
NSMutableDictionary * d = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[d setObject:value forKey:key];
```

The `d` `NSMutableDictionary` is still `NSDictionary`, see in screenshot. And, of course, application crashes then executing `[d setObject:value for:key]`
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that your `value` is `nil`, and you can't set a `nil` value into a dictionary.

Don't worry about the `__NSCFDictionary *` and `NSDictionary` stuff that you see in the variable inspector.  You most definitely have a mutable dictionary.  What you see in the inspector is artifacts of how `NSMutableDictionary` is implemented (as a class cluster).